# Generate apk failed :The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, android

I have finished app on android studio, everything work fine but when try to generate apk, It won't work

The error say this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':thingNote:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Kerja\percobaan\Omni-Notes-5.1.0\thingNote\..\bin\seeds.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

can you help me how to fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled `ProGuard` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your gradle file if there is minifyEnabled true  change it to minifyEnabled false in the app.gradle file.

And then let me know. Also try changing the directory of apk , I mean try to change the root where apk is going to save after build.

Comment: feel free to ask the questions